# How to initialise a NSObject Class

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsobject

I am trying to pass a NSDictionary object over to my NSObject Class, so that I can use the object elements in my current viewController however I am having some trouble initialing it.

This is what my NSObject class Method header looks like

**NSObjectClass.m**

```
- (GetSeriesDictionary *)assignSeriesDictionaryData:(NSMutableDictionary*)seriesDictionaryData {

    // Initialize values
    seriesID = [[seriesDictionaryData valueForKey:@"SeriesID"] integerValue];

    seriesType = [[seriesDictionaryData valueForKey:@"SeriesType"] integerValue];

//...
```

Then inside the view controller I am trying to use this NSObject like this

**ViewController.m**

```
// inside random method
    GetSeriesDictionary *getSeriesObj = [[GetSeriesSeriesDictionary alloc] init];
    getSeriesObj = (GetSeriesSeriesDictionary *)series; // this is where I am having the problem

    NSLog(@"%i", getSeriesObj.seriesID);
//..
```

But then I am reviving this error

```
-[__NSDictionaryM seriesID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8de940
```

So I would like some help with initialing my NSObject so that I can call the elements out of the object like

```
getSeriesObj.seriesID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just cast the objects. You need to call `assignSeriesDictionaryData:` that you've created.

```
// inside random method
GetSeriesDictionary *getSeriesObj = [[GetSeriesSeriesDictionary alloc] init];
[getSeriesObj assignSeriesDictionaryData:series]; 

NSLog(@"%i", getSeriesObj.seriesID);
//..
```

Also, as you may have noted, I'd not have a NSObjectClass. That mapping fits better on GetSeriesDictionary itself (you can create a custom init that does that).

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply, one thing though can you explaine the last sentence in your answer... I dont quite understand it :( not sure what you mean by mapping etc.

Comment: I meant converting a dictionary object to your custom one. I didn't understand why you created `NSObjectClass`. You can put `assignSeriesDictionaryData:` method in `GetSeriesDictionary` class, and instead of return a new instance, just set the values on the current one.

Comment: ahh I understand. Well the reason I created the object is to convert the data into their correct data types.. also some of the elements are  abit weird like 5;5;5;5;5 in which case this NSObject will put those types of elements into arrays etc.

Comment: You can split this logic on each custom object. If you want to keep it on a single class, I'd change its name, and make its methods belonging to class (not to the instance). It's called Factory pattern.